# Vertical tab in Delphi string on Android using FMX

Tags: android, delphi, string-formatting, firemonkey

could someone explain me, why horizontal tab in string works on Windows, but not on Android ? Using Delphi 10.1 Berlin, FireMonkey. Or how to use tab and other special chars on Android :)

```
procedure TFMain.Text1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Text1.Text:= 'first:' + chr(9) + '1' + #10 + 'second:' + #9 + '2';
end;
```

Result on Windows:

```
first:  1
second: 2
```

Result on Android:

```
first: 1
second: 2
```

What I need - align text in columns in TText, TMemo, hints and so on. 
Best regards.

Comment: *Vertical tab*, *horizontal tab*, *white spaces*. Terminology is shaky. But what characters exactly are in `Text1.Text` after that code is executed? **Please list the character codes**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a problem of object size; Resize the height of Text1 for greater size and mark Text1.wordwrap =True

Comment: No, Text1 is big enough, full screen size.